# How does the `tap` function get ignored?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitapgesturerecognizer

Following Apple's [Guide to build a MealKeeper app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1), I was able to create a text field and an image view. After dragging and dropping the `UITapGestureRecognizer` on top of the image view, I added the code to hide the keyboard by making the text field to resign.
[image: MealKeeper]

When I run this code in simulator, I first click on the text field, the keyboard appears.
Then I click on the image view, the keyboard does not get hide.

How does the `tap` function get ignored?

Comment: Please don't link to your entire project expecting it to be downloaded and debugged. Include necessary information here, so that the question is self-contained.

Comment: The only reason that I uploaded my project (which has very few lines of code) is that IDE (XCode in this case) might have done something behind the scene in some of the meta data files. I don't know if those changes are relevant or whether I need to change my project type or anything.

Comment: ...you also don't need to include the answer in your question; that's exactly what the accepted answer function is for.

Comment: I would like to help future researchers by adding a screenshot. I could have added a screenshot in the comment to the accepted answer for clarification purpose. However, SO does not have a screenshot upload in the comment area.

Comment: Fair enough; in that case please either add your own answer (this is allowed, yes!) or edit it into the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the gesture to you imageview, create an IBOutlet to your imageview and add the following to 'viewDidLoad'.

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("tap:"))
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion reminds me that I missed one step: Setting the image view attribute `User Interaction Enabled`.

Answer (score 1):

For learners who rely on the IDE to fix this issue, you need to enable the image view's user interaction.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add touch delegates and resign text field keyboard on that.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
if(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan) {
    [self.myTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is a bit different in the latest Swift 2.3

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBAction func tap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(ViewController.tap(_:)))
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}
}
```